# Optimizing fully 3d-printable shaft detent/index mechanism

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms, 3d-printing

I am building a vertical-mount deployable tool storage device. Normally, it is in the "locked" position, but when I turn a knob, it becomes unlocked, unfolds, and the tools inside can be accessed. To "unlock", this knob needs to be turned exactly 90 degrees to release, and turned 90 degrees again to lock it.

In order to make it feel good, I decided to spring-load this mechanism by adding a roughly square section to the knob's key shaft, and pressing a "D"-shaped profile against it to provide the indexing function. An additional feature of this mechanism is that it also makes sure the key/knob assembly stays captive in the part, because once the detent part slips into the grove with the detent, it prevents the knob from simply being pulled out. The main challenge of this is that to fit in the design, it needed to be extremely compact. The OD of the key shaft is only 9 mm and the detent is around 1.4mm thick, which is quite small for the 3d printer.

[image: Section view of design]

Here is another screenshot of the whole key-knob-detent assembly.

[image: Transparent view]

**Question:**

I have printed and assembled this, and the mechanism works. Unfortunately though, the restorative force that it imparts on the knob is quite weak, and although I suspect this could be improved with a stronger spring (making the zig-zag thicker in this case), there is almost no force guiding the knob into one of the 90° positions if it's in the middle of a turn (at eg 45°) and when the knob is at a 90° position, there is quite a bit of slop in the mechanism.

- How can I change the geometry of the detent/knob shaft to increase the "restorative" force which drives the knob into perfectly horizontal or vertical?
- How can I reduce slop in the mechanism when the knob/key is in one of the desired positions?
- Can someone point me towards resources where people have design guidelines for stuff like this or existing 3d-print designs that use shaft-indexing detent mechanisms like this?

Comment: I assume with *slop* you mean *slope*, however I am still having trouble understanding what exactly you mean with *"How can I reduce slop in the mechanism when the knob/key is in one of the desired positions?"*

Comment: @NMech `slop in the mechanism` means that the mechanism is loosely fitting ... lots of undesired movement

Comment: @NMech slop is also known as backlash, wobble, play, etc. The specific issue is that while the knob is in one of the "lock" positions, I can still move it in either direction by about 20° with basically no force. This causes the knob to often sit crooked

Comment: Have you tried making the detent more pointed? The "ramp angle" that the knob has to ride up is fairly shallow. I've had poor results with 3d printed springs long term personally.